Section 5 Complete Linear Ordering in chapter 4, introduction to set theory, by Thomas Jech

5.1 Definition Let $(P,<)$ be a linearly ordered set. A gap is a pair $(A,B)$ of sets such that
(a) $A$ and $B$ are nonempty disjoint subsets of $P$ and $A \cup B = P$.
(b) If $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, then $a \lt b$.
(c) $A$ does not have a greatest element and $B$ does not have a least element.


On the other hand, let $S$ be a nonempty set, bounded from above. Let $ A=\{x\mid x \leq s \text{ for some } s \in S\}, B=\{x\mid x \gt s \text{ for every } s \in S\}.$
The reader is asked to verify that the pair $(A, B)$ satisfies the first two properties (a) and (b) in the definition of a gap.

Why $B=\{x\mid x \gt s \text{ for every } s \in S\}$ is nonempty? If $P=\{x \in\mathbb{Q}\mid,x\leq 1\}, S=\{1\}$, then it seems that $B=\emptyset$.

In your example, $S$ isn't bounded from above in $P$.

@RobertShore why?A set is bounded from above if it has an upper bound. By the definition, 1 is an upper bound of S, am i correct?
